# Binding error on executing prepared statement IBM_DB in python

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud, command-line-interface

I am trying to execute a prepared statement to a db2 on IBM Cloud. I only want to run the query if a `data_array` is populated which I have controlled that it is. This is my code:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
ibm_db.autocommit(conn, ibm_db.SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF)

ins_sql = "insert into MY_TABLE (ID, NAME) values (?, ?)"
ins_stm = ibm_db.prepare(conn, ins_sql)

if data_array:
    for data in data_array:
        ibm_db.bind_param(ins_stm, 1, data['ID'])
        ibm_db.bind_param(ins_stm, 2, data['NAME'])
        ibm_db.execute(ins_stm)

    ibm_db.commit(conn)
```

When I run it I get the following error in the `ibm_db.execute(ins_stm)`-line.

> Exception: Binding Error 3: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0102E  Invalid conversion. SQLSTATE=07006 SQLCODE=-99999

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have `data` and `event`...?!

Comment: Edit your question to give the Db2-server details (operating-system, Db2 version) and the encoding for the database. Old Db2-LUW versions sometimes threw this exception when source data was variable width UTF-8 but target column/table/tablespace encoding was fixed-width, long since fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is a copy & paste error. You have `data` in the array, but use `event` to get the array part. Change that to `data['ID']` etc.

Comment: Typo on my end unfortunately... Fixed that now. The error remains.